# Click event is not working for the Button Sin Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

Till yesterday my code was working to click this button, but now when I am trying to use the same code, the button is just getting highlighted and not clicked. Have tried every possible way to clicking it by surfing on internet and finding solutions but nothing works.

[image]

```
                               IWebElement ele = river.FindElement(By.Id("btnToTranslate"));
                               IJavaScriptExecutor executors = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;                                                    executors.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", ele);
                               ele.Click();
                               ele.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);//even tried sending enter button but nothing happens.
```

the element what I am trying to fetch is

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: `driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnToTranslate")).Click();` - do this, there should be some error

Comment: No error. It just gets highlighted and does not take click. Even tried with the enter function but still does not work. Strange

Comment: `new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Xpath("//span[text()='Translate']"))).Click();` - try this

Comment: throwing this error {"element click intercepted: Element <span id=\"btnTo...-announce\" class=\"a-button-text\" aria-hidden=\"true\">Translate</span> is not clickable at point (580, 138). Other element would receive the click: <input class=\"a-button-input\" type=\"submit\" aria-labelledby=\"btnToTranslate-announce\">\n  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)"}

Comment: Are you launching the browser in full scree mode ?

Comment: Yes i am launching it in a full screen mode

Comment: okay where is this element is present in UI ? I mean if you have to interact with it manually, will you scroll down ?

Comment: It is always on the top. No i would not scroll down and access the element. I can just click on it when the page loads and it gets translated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to wait using explicit wait and then use Actions class to click :

```
var element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Xpath("//span[text()='Translate']")))
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Still not working. I think waiting for the element would not work cause at the end the button is getting highlighted.

Comment: Just checked with the code. When the button is getting highlighted, in the first line the class="-button a-button-primary" is changing to class="-button a-button-primary a-button-focus" which means the button is getting focused. just not clicked

Comment: You were getting elementIntercept exception, that's generally comes when the element is not into selenium view port. So to resolve that we have used actions class. What error or exception it threw ?

Comment: And I would recommend to use the xpath with exact matching text in this scenario.

Comment: Jus realized that chrome was updated today and the click is not working due to that.

Comment: oh, in general session should not have created in case chrome upgrade

Comment: I tried using this code in mozilla and it is working. I guess Chrome has the issue